# How to change WndProc for a listview control

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I am trying to change a Wndproc for a listview control so the first parameter in wndproc return the control handle that receives the message, the problem is when I change it other functions stop working (I cannot insert columns or items anymore), is there something I need to change or return in order to keep using the same wndproc for all the controls

WNDPROC same for all controls:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK staticWndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){
    std::cout << (int)hwnd << " control received msg:" << uMsg << std::endl; //This must work
    //event = { msg:uMsg, target:(int)hwnd, x:0, y:0, button:0, key:0 };
    switch (uMsg){
        case WM_DESTROY:
            std::cout << "window says bye " << std::endl;
            PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
            break;
        default:
            //msghandlercall(event); //this is handled not in c++
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

after calling to `SetWindowLongPtr(handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)staticWndProc);` insert messages are not working as default

```
int createColumn(HWND listhandle, int indexCol, char *Text, int width){
    LVCOLUMN lvc={0};
    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    lvc.cx = width;
    lvc.pszText = Text;
    lvc.iSubItem = indexCol;
    //return ListView_InsertColumn(listhandle, indexCol, &lvc);
    SendMessage(listhandle,LVM_INSERTCOLUMN,indexCol,(LPARAM)&lvc);
    return 1;
}
void createColumns(HWND listhandle, std::vector<LPSTR> columns){
    for(int i=0; i<columns.size(); i++) createColumn(listhandle, i, columns[i], 50);
}
int createItem(HWND listhandle, const std::vector<LPSTR>& row){ 
    LVITEM lvi = {0};
    //lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    // lvi.pszText = row[0];
    int ret = ListView_InsertItem(listhandle, &lvi);
    if(ret>-1) for(unsigned i=0; i<row.size(); i++)
        ListView_SetItemText(listhandle, ret, i, row[i]);
    return ret;
} 
HWND createList(int parenthandle=0){
    if(parenthandle==0) parenthandle=(int)GetDesktopWindow();
    HWND handle = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, "",WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS, 
                            10, 10, 300, 100,  (HWND)parenthandle, /*(HMENU)ID_LIST*/NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
    if(!handle){ std::cerr << "Failed to create list\n"; return 0; }
    SetWindowLongPtr(handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)staticWndProc);
    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(handle, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
    createColumns(handle,{"col1","col2","col3"});
    createItem(handle,{"item1.1","item1.2","item1.3","item1.4"});
    createItem(handle,{"item2.1","item2.2","item2.3","item2.4"});
    return handle;
}
```

**NOTE** I tried adding wndproc with `SetWindowSubclass()` but an error occurs:
`error C2664: 'BOOL IsolationAwareSetWindowSubclass(HWND,SUBCLASSPROC,UINT_PTR,DWORD_PTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LRESULT (__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'SUBCLASSPROC' [build\binding.vcxproj]`

Comment: The WNDPROC you are using only handles the Destroy message - so that's the only think you can do using that WNDPROC.  You might need to add more messages to the WNDPROC.

Comment: You need to get the existing callback for the control and call that not  `DefWindowProc` In the default case statement.

Comment: Calling DefWindowProc() for a sub-classed window actually *bypasses* the WndProc() of the window.  So sure, lots of stuff stops working.  You must call the *original* WndProc, the one you are supposed to retrieve first with GetWindowLongPtr.  Which of course means that you cannot use a single WndProc to destroy them all.  Try to fall [in the pit of success](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you subclass a window procedure using `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`, it returns the previous window procedure that is being replaced.  Your subclass procedure must pass unhandled messages to that previous procedure using `CallWindowProc()` instead of `DefWindowProc()`.  This is stated as much in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx):

> Calling `SetWindowLongPtr` with the `GWLP_WNDPROC` index creates a subclass of the window class used to create the window. An application can subclass a system class, but should not subclass a window class created by another process. The `SetWindowLongPtr` function creates the window subclass by changing the window procedure associated with a particular window class, causing the system to call the new window procedure instead of the previous one. **An application must pass any messages not processed by the new window procedure to the previous window procedure by calling `CallWindowProc`. This allows the application to create a chain of window procedures**.

You are not doing that, which is why your code is failing.

Try this instead:

```
WNDPROC prevWndProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK staticWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //...
    return CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

HWND createList(HWND parenthandle = NULL)
{
    if (!parenthandle) parenthandle = GetDesktopWindow();

    HWND handle = CreateWindow(..., parenthandle, ...);
    if (!handle) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create list\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    prevWndProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)staticWndProc);
    if (!prevWndProc) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to subclass list\n";
        DestroyWindow(handle);
        return NULL;
    }

    ...

    return handle;
}
```

That being said, you really should not be using `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)` at all.  It is unsafe for exact this reason (amongst others).  You should be using [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) instead:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK staticSubClass(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    //...

    if (uMsg == WM_NCDESTROY) {
        // NOTE: this requirement is NOT stated in the documentation,
        // but it is stated in Raymond Chen's blog article...
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, staticSubClass, uIdSubclass);
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

HWND createList(HWND parenthandle = NULL)
{
    if (!parenthandle) parenthandle = GetDesktopWindow();

    HWND handle = CreateWindow(..., parenthandle, ...);
    if (!handle) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create list\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!SetWindowSubclass(handle, staticSubClass, 1, 0)){
        std::cerr << "Failed to subclass list\n";
        DestroyWindow(handle);
        return NULL; 
    }

    ...

    return handle;
}
```

See MSDN for more details:

[Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx)

[Safer subclassing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883)